# jQuery toggle left sidebar menu with content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a sidebar which is open by default, i want to be able to click a menu icon and my sidebar slides in to show more of the content:

```
 #sidebar {
  width: 210px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: #2a3542;
 }

 #main-content {
  margin-left: 210px;
 }

 <div class="navbar">toggle icon in here</div>
 <div id="sidebar">sidebar content here</div>
 <section id="main-content">main page content here</section>
```

I want to be able to toggle the menu, but then im guessing i would have to add and remove the margin-left on to the #main-content?

Any help would be great
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>This will work ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ktk7z/2/))</del>

<del>$('.navbar').on('click', function(){
        $('#sidebar, #main-content').toggle();
    });</del>

<del>Once the element is hidden, you don't need to remove the margin or any other style of that element because, it's already hidden.</del>

**Update :** Using `jQuery UI`'s `slide` ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ktk7z/6/))

```
$('.navbar').on('click', function(){
    $('#sidebar').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
    $('#main-content').animate({
        'margin-left' : $('#main-content').css('margin-left') == '0px' ? '210px' : '0px'
    }, 1000);
});
```

**Update :** Also you may try this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ktk7z/5/)), using `.animate()` no `jQuery UI`

```
$('.navbar').on('click', function(){
    if( $('#sidebar').is(':visible') ) {
        $('#sidebar').animate({ 'width': '0px' }, 'slow', function(){
            $('#sidebar').hide();
        });
        $('#main-content').animate({ 'margin-left': '0px' }, 'slow');
    }
    else {
        $('#sidebar').show();
        $('#sidebar').animate({ 'width': '210px' }, 'slow');
        $('#main-content').animate({ 'margin-left': '210px' }, 'slow');
    }
});
```

Comment: i only require the sidebar to be hidden, so im only toggling the sidebar so i can get more of the main-content area in view. So sidebar is open by default, i click the icon to hide it, the main-content area shifts over in full view. I click the icon again and the sidebar pushes the main-content area over so they are then both in view?